# Swift: Checking progress on SKActions

Tags: ios, swift, animation, sprite-kit, sprite

I have a couple sprites in a swift game that have identical action lists (technically [SKAction]). They're all at different points in the action sequence, and I need to rank them in order of most complete (with the action) to least complete. How do I get the progress of a sprite (or at least the step of the action it's on)? Preferably, I'd like to get the percentage of completion for the step it's on.

For the sake of sample code:

```
    let sprite1 = SKShapeNode.init(rectOf: CGSize.init(width: 20, height: 20), cornerRadius: 5)
    let sprite2 = SKShapeNode.init(rectOf: CGSize.init(width: 20, height: 20), cornerRadius: 5)
    let sprite3 = SKShapeNode.init(rectOf: CGSize.init(width: 20, height: 20), cornerRadius: 5)

    sprite1.position = CGPoint(x: -100, y: 0)
    sprite2.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    sprite3.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 0)

    let sequence : [SKAction] = [SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: 50, dy: 0), duration: 1.5),
                                 SKAction.rotate(byAngle: CGFloat(M_PI / 2), duration: 1.0),
                                 SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 50), duration: 1.5),
                                 SKAction.rotate(byAngle: CGFloat(M_PI / 2), duration: 1.0),
                                 SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: -50, dy: 0), duration: 1.5)]

    sprite1.run(SKAction.sequence(sequence))
    //wait 1 second
    sprite2.run(SKAction.sequence(sequence))
    //wait another second
    sprite3.run(SKAction.sequence(sequence))

    var spriteAccord : [SKSpriteNode] = //insert ranking code
```

Comment: Please post your real code, this doesn't compile

Comment: do you need to rank based on time, or what action they are in

Comment: It would be what action they're in (as I forgot to mention that they can run at different speeds). So I'm gonna take a dictionary of start-times and use the different speeds to calculate 'distance' along the sequence, and use distance traveled to get rankings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the speed of the sprite is constant (AKA no bullet time effect) I would just use a dictionary to store starting times:

```
var startingTimes = [SKNode:NSTimeInterval]()
```

Then store when a sprite starts his sequence

```
sprite1.run(SKAction.sequence(sequence))
startingTimes[sprite1 as! SKNode] = currentTime
```

Finally, sort by the startingTime

```
let sortedStartingTimes = startingTimes.sort(){
                          (time1,time2)->Bool in 
                          return time1 <= time2
                      }
```

Then, just iterate through the dictionary, or grab the first item,  whatever you need to do here.

This can be popped into playgrounds to test the above code:

```
var startingTimes = [String:NSTimeInterval]()
startingTimes["A"] = 1
startingTimes["C"] = 3
startingTimes["B"] = 2

let sortedStartingTimes = startingTimes.sort(){
    (time1,time2)->Bool in
    return time1 <= time2
}
print("start")
for time in startingTimes
{
    print(time)
}
print("sort")
for time in sortedStartingTimes
{
    print(time)
}
```

To get the percentage of completion is a little more complex.  You need to take your currentTime  - startingTime,  then figure out based on this  where you are at in your sprite.

So I have a total of 3 steps,  each 1 second.

My currentTime - startingTime is 1.5 seconds.

```
var deltaTime = currentTime - startingTime
```

I take 1.5 - step 1 time, so result is .5 seconds

```
deltaTime -= step1Time
```

deltaTime > 0, I am in a new step

I take .5 - step 2 time, so result is .5 seconds

```
deltaTime -= step2Time
```

deltaTime <= 0  I am in this step

so deltaTime / step2time ,  that is my percentage in the step2 timeline

```
  let completionPercentage = deltaTime / step2Time
```

Answer (score 1):

You can insert [runBlock](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/runBlock:) actions between your existing actions. In the block you can then increment counters to track the progress of each node through the actions.